# In android, how to implement 'Multi-track Audio Support' using Chromecast?

Tags: android, audio, chromecast, google-cast

I need to implement `Multi-track Audio Support` feature in Sender application. Means, When user casts any video/movie on TV using Chromecast, then on sender application, user should be able to see all available audio tracks and choose desired audio track to cast on TV.

In Developers website, I saw `Tracks API`, in that `MediaTrack` object, which can be used to configure a track.
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender#tracks

Here, I am not getting, how to fetch all available audio tracks from selected mp4 file? Can anyone provide the direction to work with this?

what will be the role of `receiver application`, regarding this?

I looked at given reference sample app. From that app, I am clear of how to set `MediaTracks`.
https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android﻿

I am not getting how to extract audio tracks from mp4 file, so that we can set them as `MediaTracks`?
Is this part needs to be done in receiver app?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.﻿

Comment: Are the tracks "embedded" in your mp4 or they are separate external files? What s the format?

Comment: yes, need to show audio tracks which are 'embedded' in video/movie file. and audio can in format like aac, mp3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, in the Cast SDK, there is no support for multiple embedded audio tracks in an mp4 file

Comment: Is there way to somehow provide Cast SDK audio track streams?